# How do I access a specific index value in AWS CDK step functions using the "Iterating a Loop Using Lambda" example

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

**Use Case:** The [Iterating a Loop Using Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html) example offers a solution that allows one to loop through an array using `Choice` state. I would like to use the index of the iterator as a means of accessing a specific element in an array.

[image: Iterating a Loop Using Lambda]

**AWS CDK Code:**

```
this.iterator = new LambdaInvoke(this, "iterator", {
  lambdaFunction: stepFunctionTasksLambdaStack.iterator,
  payloadResponseOnly: true,
  comment: "Manage iterating over the array of configurable product skus",
  retryOnServiceExceptions: true,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(3),
});

this.countReached = new Choice(this, "Count Reached?");

this.encodeSku = new LambdaInvoke(this, "Encode Simple Product SKU", {
  lambdaFunction: stepFunctionTasksLambdaStack.encodeURIComponent,
  payloadResponseOnly: true,
  comment: "Encode the SKU to make it suitable for querying the Magento API with",
  retryOnServiceExceptions: true,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(3),
});
```

Where could I concatenate the index value the iterator is on for `this.encodeSku`, plus the array of skus? It'd have to be something like `input: "$.arrayOfSkus"["$.iterator.index"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CDK, the solution is to create a `payload` where we use `TaskInput.fromObject` to access the information.

```
this.pickSku = new LambdaInvoke(this, "Choose The SKU", {
  lambdaFunction: stepFunctionTasksLambdaStack.arrayElementSelector,
  inputPath: "$.augmentArrayAndIndex",
  payloadResponseOnly: true,
  comment: "Manage iterating over the array of configurable product skus",
  retryOnServiceExceptions: true,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(3),
  payload: TaskInput.fromObject({
    "array": JsonPath.stringAt("$.[LOCATION_OF_INFORMATION]"),
    "index": JsonPath.numberAt("$.[LOCATION_OF_INFORMATION]")
  })
});
```